# Reading multiple lines in java using scanner

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in a sample input:

```
3 //amount of games

//Game 1
2 2 //questions lies
bird 1 s //bird 1 a swan?
yes //answer
bird 2 d //bird 2 a duck?
no //answer

3 1
total d 4 and total g 7
yes
bird 1 s and bird 2 d and bird 3 s
yes
bird 1 g or bird 4 g
yes

2 0
total d 1
yes
bird 6 s or bird 1 d
yes
```

How can I read this input in terms of based on the integer there are 3 Games that we are going to do. I need to store everything and then go from there.

This is what I have so far, I am hoping I am on the right track

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Games = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        for(int i = 0; i == Games; i++){
             //go through game 1 and store them
             //repeat until game 3
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking? How to store the input? Are you getting an error? If your current approach is correct?

Comment: yes, how can I store all those inputs? My current approach is incomplete, I am not sure how to store all those inputs.

Comment: What are you trying to store them in? What do you need to do with this data?

Comment: I dont want to post the full question, but this is what it should be doing. 
Game 1

Bob asks two questions in the first game, and Alices lies in both her responses.

Since Alice said that the first bird is a swan, and she lied, you know that it cannot be a swan, and you should output dg.

Alice said that the second bird is not a duck, and shed lied. Thus, you know that the bird must be a duck, and you should output d.

Comment: Right now I am just trying to figure out how to store the data thats being given to me.

Comment: You can use array, arraylist, make a lot of variables... You have to chose but i think array is best for this, you make for loop and circle as many times as you want, store input in arrays

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Scanner.next()` instead of `Scanner.nextLine()` so you can read single word/number at a time. Your for loop is wrong you need to change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Games; i++)
// or you can also use
while (Games-- > 0)
```

I prefer the while loop because you don't want to keep track of the loop number.

For example:

```
public class Solution { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
        int games = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        // loop for games
        while (games-- > 0) {
            int questions = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            int lie = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            // loop for questions
            while (questions-- > 0) {

                // do whatever logic you want to do and print the answer
            }
        }
    }
}
```